# iOS swift margin between tableHeader and cell's

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview with `tableHeaderView`. when I run the app the annoying margin is between cell's and tableHeaderView as you seen in image.

[image]

How can I remove this margin?
thanks

P.S : I use `self.navigationController?.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` in `viewDidLoad()` but nothing changes.

Comment: Try to use debug view hierarchy, it might give you a clue: https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6

Comment: did you try reducing size of tableHeader?

Comment: @Misha yes but nothing changes

Comment: have you tried      self.view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero in viewDidLoad

Comment: @Rahul yes but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

Write this line :- 
`self.navigationController?.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` in `viewDidAppear()` method.

Comment: How is that going to be different than having it in the `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: viewDidLoad is called when the view is not actually visible. It's called exactly once, when the view controller is first loaded into memory.

Comment: But is the property going to be reassigned at any point? If it isn't reassigned, then I don't see how this will make a difference.

Comment: The UIViewController class provides the infrastructure for managing the views in Apple doc :- https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller & UIViewController Lifecycle :- https://rdkw.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle/

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to understand what you're saying here. I know what you mean about the `viewDidLoad` being called once during loading, and `viewDidAppear` multiple times, just whenever the view appears. That makes sense, in fact I already knew that. But, unless you are saying that something changes the variable at some point in the viewcontroller's lifecycle (and I can't see what would), I don't see how the amount of times (and when) it is called becomes relevant. You should be able to set it in either method with the same consequences. Please help clarify.